# Euclidean Distance from Ideal best and from Ideal Worst

Tags: python, pandas

Let's consider this table below:

| Mobile | Battery(mAh) | RAM(GB) | Storage(GB) | ED from Ideal best | ED from Ideal worst |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sansung | 1000 | 4 | 2 |  |  |
| iPhone | 8000 | 6 | 3 |  |  |
| Motorola | 3000 | 3 | 1 |  |  |

> Formula for ED from Ideal best  = √(( Battery(mAh)- Max of Battery(mAh))^2  + (RAM(GB) - Max of RAM(GB)    )^2 + ( Storage(GB) - Max of Storage(GB))^2)

> Formula for ED from Ideal Worst = √(( Battery(mAh)- Min of Battery(mAh))^2 + (RAM(GB) - Minof RAM(GB) )^2 + ( Storage(GB) - Min of Storage(GB))^2)

> For instance, value for Samsung mobile should be √((1000-8000)^2+(4-6)^2+(2-3)^2) = 7000.00035714

> Can Anyone help me to write a function in Python where these two formulas can apply for each rows for ED from Ideal best   and ED from Ideal worst?

So far I've tried this:

```
df["Euclidean Distance from ideal best"]= np.sqrt((df["Battery(mAh)"]-df["Battery(mAh)"].max()).pow(2) + (df["RAM(GB)"]-df["RAM(GB)"].max()).pow(2) + (df["Storage(GB)"]-df["Storage(GB)"].max()).pow(2))
```

Comment: what's df1? you've written `df1["RAM(GB)"]` but `df1` is undefined

Comment: df1 is the dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine by me. Just change the typo `df1`->`df`:

```
df["Euclidean Distance from ideal best"] = np.sqrt(
    (df["Battery(mAh)"] - df["Battery(mAh)"].max())**2 + 
    (df["RAM(GB)"]-df["RAM(GB)"].max())**2 + 
    (df["Storage(GB)"]-df["Storage(GB)"].max())**2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you've written should work fine (just write `df` instead of `df1`, which is undefined):

```py
df["Euclidean Distance from ideal best"] = np.sqrt(
    (df["Battery(mAh)"] - df["Battery(mAh)"].max()).pow(2)
    + (df1["RAM(GB)"] - df["RAM(GB)"].max()).pow(2)
    + (df1["Storage(GB)"] - df["Storage(GB)"].max()).pow(2)
)
```

you'll get

```
>>> df
      Mobile  ...  Euclidean Distance from ideal best
0   Sansung   ...                         7000.000357
1    iPhone   ...                            0.000000
2  Motorola   ...                         5000.001300
```

which matches your expected output

For the other column:

```py
df["Euclidean Distance from ideal worst"] = np.sqrt(
    (df["Battery(mAh)"] - df["Battery(mAh)"].min()).pow(2)
    + (df1["RAM(GB)"] - df["RAM(GB)"].min()).pow(2)
    + (df1["Storage(GB)"] - df["Storage(GB)"].min()).pow(2)
)
```